# Joomla - Virtuemart invoice/delivery note without content

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a strange problem with invoice and delivery note. It displays only the name of company in top and nothing more in pdf. However, at print choice (in CMS) it displays whole the content.

Moreover, when I click on invoive or delivery note, it opens them as pdf in browser instead of download them. Is this a normal reaction?

I use joomla 2.5 and VM 2.6.8. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't have set the vmsafe folder for invoices.

I went to CMS - Virtuemart - configuration - configuration - (in tab) Templates

and I set in safe path: /home/username*/vmsafe

*the username of website